# Calculation the elements of different sized matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation

Can anybody help me to find out the method to calculate the elements of different sized matrix in **Matlab** ?

Let say that I have 2 matrices with numbers.
Example:

```
A=[1 2 3;
   4 5 6;
   7 8 9]

B=[10 20 30;
   40 50 60]
```

At first,we need to find **maximum number** in each column.
In this case, Ans=[40 50 60].

And then,we need to find ****coefficient** (k)**.
Coefficient(k) is equal to 1 divided by *quantity of column of matrix A*.
In this case, **coefficient (k)**=1/3=0.33.

I wanna create matrix **C** filling with calculation.

**Example in MS Excel.**
[image]

H4 = ABS((C2-C6)/C9)*0.33+ABS((D2-D6)/D9)*0.33+ABS((E2-E6)/E9)*0.33

I4 = ABS((C3-C6)/C9)*0.33+ABS((D3-D6)/D9)*0.33+ABS((E3-E6)/E9)*0.33

J4 = ABS((C4-C6)/C9)*0.33+ABS((D4-D6)/D9)*0.33+ABS((E4-E6)/E9)*0.33

And then (Like above)

H5 = ABS((C2-C7)/C9)*0.33+ABS((D2-D7)/D9)*0.33+ABS((E2-E7)/E9)*0.33

I5 = ABS((C3-C7)/C9)*0.33+ABS((D3-D7)/D9)*0.33+ABS((E3-E7)/E9)*0.33

J5 = ABS((C4-C7)/C9)*0.33+ABS((D4-D7)/D9)*0.33+ABS((E4-E7)/E9)*0.33

C =

[image]

0.34 =|(1-10)|/40*0.33+|(2-20)|/50*0.33+|(3-30)|/60*0.33

0.28 =|(4-10)|/40*0.33+|(5-20)|/50*0.33+|(6-30)|/60*0.33

0.22 =|(7-10)|/40*0.33+|(8-20)|/50*0.33+|(9-30)|/60*0.33

0.95 =|(1-40)|/40*0.33+|(2-50)|/50*0.33+|(3-60)|/60*0.33

0.89 =|(4-40)|/40*0.33+|(5-50)|/50*0.33+|(6-60)|/60*0.33

0.83 =|(7-40)|/40*0.33+|(8-50)|/50*0.33+|(9-60)|/60*0.33

***Actually A is a 15x4 matrix and B is a 5x4 matrix.***
Perhaps,the matrices dimensions are more than this matrices (variables).
How can i write this in Matlab?

Thanks you!

Comment: If you want the maximum, I would strongly recommend to read the documentation for the `max` function...

Comment: Thanks! Daniel. Max function is useful but not enough for our case.:(

Comment: My answer took a lot of effort because the way you are calculating your values is not clear **unless** you trace through the Excel code.  Nevertheless, I have provided an answer for you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by `maximum number in each column`, you mean columnwise maximum after vertically concatenating `A` and `B`, you can try this one-liner -

```
sum(abs(bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,permute(A,[3 1 2]),permute(B,[1 3 2])),permute(max(vertcat(A,B)),[1 3 2]))),3)./size(A,2)
```

Output -

```
ans =
    0.3450    0.2833    0.2217
    0.9617    0.9000    0.8383
```

If by `maximum number in each column`, you mean columnwise maximum of `B`, you can try -

```
sum(abs(bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,permute(A,[3 1 2]),permute(B,[1 3 2])),permute(max(B),[1 3 2]))),3)./size(A,2)
```

The output for this case stays the same as the previous case, owing to the values of `A` and `B`.

Comment: @user3455066 Welcome! So `by maximum number in each column` you meant just the max of `B` or `A` and `B` concatenated vertically? I will cancel out the other one from the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like so.  Let's assume that `A` and `B` are defined as you did before:

```
A = vec2mat(1:9, 3)
B = vec2mat(10:10:60, 3)

A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9

B = 

    10    20    30
    40    50    60
```

`vec2mat` will transform a vector into a matrix.  You simply specify how many columns you want, and it will automatically determine the right amount of rows to transform the vector into a correctly shaped matrix (thanks @LuisMendo!).  Let's also define more things based on your post:

```
maxCol = max(B); %// Finds maximum of each column in B
coefK = 1 / size(A,2); %// 1 divided by number of columns in A
```

I am going to assuming that `coefK` is multiplied by **every element in `A`**.  You would thus compute your desired matrix as so:

```
cellMat = arrayfun(@(x) sum(coefK*(bsxfun(@rdivide, ...
          abs(bsxfun(@minus, A, B(x,:))), maxCol)), 2), 1:size(B,1), ...
          'UniformOutput', false);

outputMatrix = cell2mat(cellMat).'
```

You thus get:

```
outputMatrix =

    0.3450    0.2833    0.2217
    0.9617    0.9000    0.8383
```

Seems like a bit much to chew right?  Let's go through this slowly.

- Let's start with the `bsxfun(@minus, A, B(x,:))` call.  What we are doing is taking the `A` matrix and subtracting with a particular row in `B` called `x`.  In our case, `x` is either `1` or `2`.  This is equal to the number of rows we have in `B`.  What is cool about `bsxfun` is that this will subtract **every row** in `A` by this row called by `B(x,:)`.
- Next, what we need to do is divide every single number in this result by the corresponding columns found in our maximum column, defined as `maxCol`.  As such, we will call another `bsxfun` that will divide every element in the matrix outputted in the first step by their corresponding column elements in `maxCol`.
- Once we do this, we weight all of the values of each row by `coefK` (or actually **every** value in the matrix).  In our case, this is `1/3`.
- After, we then sum over all of the columns to give us our corresponding elements for each column of the output matrix for row `x`.
- As we wish to do this for **all of the rows**, going from `1, 2, 3, ...` up to as many rows as we have in `B`, we apply `arrayfun` that will substitute values of `x` going from 1, 2, 3... up to as many rows in `B`.  For each value of `x`, we will get a `numCol x 1` vector where `numCol` is the total number of columns shared by A and B.  This code will only work **if `A` and `B` share the same number of columns.**  I have not placed any error checking here.  In this case, we have 3 columns shared between both matrices.  We need to use `UniformOutput` and we set this to `false` because the output of `arrayfun` is not a single number, but a vector.
- After we do this, this returns each row of the output matrix in a cell array.  We need to use `cell2mat` to transform these cell array elements into a single matrix.
- You'll notice that this is the result we want, but it is transposed due to summing along the columns in the second step.  As such, simply transpose the result and we get our final answer.

Good luck!

## Dedication

This post is dedicated to Luis Mendo and Divakar - The `bsxfun` masters.

Comment: I am sure that Luis Mendo and Divakar appreciate that their bsxfun mastery is rubbing off. Nice post.

Comment: @Floris - Thanks!  Nice seeing you around again.

Comment: +1 for making it easier for others to understand yet again! Oh btw on that title with `bsxfun`, not too sure about that, as said before too, I am just too happy to be associated with it, because it's such a wonderful tool!

Comment: @user3455066 - You're very welcome.  Even though there was a lack of information, it was still a nice challenge to try and solve it.  Great brain workout.

Comment: @Divakar - I was a former part-time instructor at my university so the objective when I write posts is to always try and ask the right questions when something isn't clear, and to clarify for everyone else.  Sometimes my posts are a bit long because I like to write them in a tutorial style so it benefits not only the OP, but anyone else who reads.  Thank you for your compliments :)

Comment: @rayryeng Which is what I love and respect about your posts and also appreciate them! Don't know if I have said this before, you are valuable to `SO` for those very reasons, so keep those help coming! :)